# Two operation with same name but with different paramteres in WSDL

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, axis

I have a wsdl (RPC encoded) which contains 2 pair of operation which have the same operation name, but have different paramters, and different input/output messages.

Here are the important parts of the wsdl (i can generate java code, and the wsdl is valid).

```
<!-- message for the first operation -->
<wsdl:message name="SomethingGoodRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="paramOne" type="xsd:int">
    </wsdl:part>
    <wsdl:part name="paramTwo" type="soapenc:string">
    </wsdl:part>
    <wsdl:part name="paramThree" type="soapenc:string">
    </wsdl:part>
    <wsdl:part name="paramFour" type="soapenc:string">
    </wsdl:part>
    <wsdl:part name="paramFive" type="soapenc:string">
    </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>

<!-- message for the second operation -->
<wsdl:message name="SomethingGoodRequest1">
    <wsdl:part name="paramOne" type="xsd:int">
    </wsdl:part>
    <wsdl:part name="paramTwo" type="soapenc:string">
    </wsdl:part>
    <wsdl:part name="paramThree" type="tns1:VerySpecialTypeForGoodThings">
    </wsdl:part>
    <wsdl:part name="paramFour" type="soapenc:string">
    </wsdl:part>
    <wsdl:part name="paramFive" type="soapenc:string">
    </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>

<!-- the operations -->
<wsdl:operation name="SomethingGood" parameterOrder="paramOne paramTwo paramThree paramFour paramFive">
    <wsdl:input message="impl:SomethingGoodRequest" name="SomethingGoodRequest" />
    <wsdl:output message="impl:SomethingGoodResponse" name="SomethingGoodResponse" />
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="SomethingGood" parameterOrder="paramOne paramTwo paramThree">
    <wsdl:input message="impl:SomethingGoodRequest1" name="SomethingGoodRequest1" />
    <wsdl:output message="impl:SomethingGoodResponse1" name="SomethingGoodResponse1" />
</wsdl:operation>

<wsdl:operation name="SomethingGood">
    <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>
    <wsdl:input name="SomethingGoodRequest">
        <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://nevermind" use="encoded"/>
    </wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:output name="SomethingGoodResponse">
        <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://nevermind" use="encoded"/>
    </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>

<wsdl:operation name="SomethingGood">
    <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>
    <wsdl:input name="SomethingGoodRequest1">
        <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://nevermind" use="encoded"/>
    </wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:output name="SomethingGoodResponse1">
        <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://nevermind" use="encoded"/>
    </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
```

The problem is, whenever i try to call the second method (from the two who share the same name) i get this exception (500 Internal Server Error):

```
faultDetail: 
       {}:return code:  500
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <soapenv:Fault>
      <faultcode>Server</faultcode>
      <faultstring>Missing operation for soapAction [] and body element [{http://nevermind/}SomethingGood] with SOAP Version [SOAP 1.1]</faultstring>
    </soapenv:Fault>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The interesting thing is, that i can call every other operation (from the java client and from SoapUI as well) without any problems, and i can call the first operation from those who share the same name.

So i can successfully SomethingGood with 5 parameters, but when i try to call the one with the 3 parameters, i get the exception described above.

Is there any workaround, or only by fixing the wsdl? (i got the wsdl, so i can't edit it by myself)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Whoever gave you this wsdl, He must have got warning while generating this kind ofwsdl. He simply ignored it. You can provide different SOAP Action in this case but again you have to edit your wsdl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it's legal to overload methods in [WSLD](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/ws/2003/01/08/randyray.html), but WS-I [basic profile](http://www.ws-i.org/Profiles/BasicProfile-1.1.html#Distinctive_Operations) disallows this feature. AXIS, JAX-WS, CXF, Spring and some other frameworks claims to be compliant with basic profile. Whoever created this WSDL probably doesn't work with java/BP compliant web services, if you're stuck with these frameworks you'll have to modify WSDL.